# Как поместить содержимое нескольких блоков в textarea, но построчно (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот есть такие соображения, двигаюсь в этом направлении, но что не понимаю...

```js
$(".parent .child").each(function(i) {
  $('.form-textarea').html($(this).eq(i).html() + '\n');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">первый</div>
  <div class="child">второй</div>
  <div class="child">третий</div>
  <div class="child">четвертый</div>
  <div class="child">пятый</div>
</div>
<textarea class="form-textarea"></textarea>
```

именно перебор с помощью `.each` хочу использовать, как более понятный и удобочитаемый для меня

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например так (на чистом `javascript`):

```js
var textArea = document.getElementById('textArea');

var list = document.querySelectorAll('.parent > .child');

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var text = list[i].innerText;
  textArea.value += text + '\n';
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">первый</div>
  <div class="child">второй</div>
  <div class="child">третий</div>
  <div class="child">четвертый</div>
  <div class="child">пятый</div>
</div>
<textarea class="form-textarea" id="textArea"></textarea>
```

Если после последней строчки не нужен перевод строки, нужно добавить условие.

Если не хочется добавлять `id` к полю `textarea` можно воспользоваться `document.querySelector('form-textarea')`.

**UPD**: в связи с обновлением вопроса:

Тогда на `jQuery` код будет таким:

```
var textArea = $('.form-textarea');
$(".parent .child").each(function(i) {
  textArea.append( $(this).text() + '\n');
})
```

Comment: внес правки в вопрос))

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов обновил

Comment: благодарю! только не совсем понимаю как это работает, по-челочески сам себе объяснить не могу.. зачем textArea поместили в textArea? что то тут я запутался.

Comment: ты из `textArea` записываешь значение `$(this).text()`, т.е. каждый раз, в `textArea` будет последнее присвоенное значение. Чтобы дописывать значение, тебе надо к существующему прибавлять следующее. Что и видно в коде. Кстати место `.html()` лучше использовать `.text()`

Comment: все теперь понял

Answer (score 2):

Не могу пока добавлять комментарии, но не могу и не поправить коллегу выше. Всё хорошо написано кроме этой строки:

```
textArea.html(textArea.html() + $(this).text() + '\n');
```

Потому что:
получается что каждый раз берётся ВЕСЬ текст из инпута, к нему прибавляется строка и уже **всё** это **снова** вставляется в инпут, лучше уж так:

```
textArea.append( $(this).text() + '\n');
```

тут просто добавляется строка после всех узлов которые уже вставлены...

Comment: Верно :) я могу внести это правкой в ответ? Не против?

Comment: Неа, не против)